# why custom size report is not seen completely in client side

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm working in Crystal report. The Report is completely Shown in Server side but when I view report in Client side it is incomplete. It displays only half size. my custom report width is 20 inch, height 15 inch. please help me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the report, page setup what is the printer configuration? It is important to "disassociate" otherwise the report will be displayed different based on the printer attached to the computer running it.